# redirect not working after DB insert

Tags: php

I run this query and it woks well by inserting the record into database but not redirecting me to the success page.

Query:

```
$query =$db->submitapp("INSERT INTO `applications` (`app_no`,`fname`,`sname`,`oname`,`sex`,`dob`,`state`,`lga`,`home_town`,`address`,`pschool`,`sclass`,`passport`,`pfname`,`psname`,`pphone`,`paddress`) VALUES('".$app_no."','".$fname."','".$sname."','".$oname."','".$sex."','".$dob."','".$state."','".$lga."','".$home_town."','".$address."','".$pschool."','".$sclass."','".$passport."','".$pfname."','".$psname."','".$pphone."','".$paddress."')");
if($query){
 $update_pin =$db->update("UPDATE card_pins SET status_pin = 1 WHERE   pin_number=$pin_num");                 
       header("location:success.php?appid=$app_no");
     }
```

This is the Error i am getting
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 162"

Comment: Also Add else part And Check Weather Query Is Executes or not

Comment: You should read up on sql injection.

Comment: ^^ which will also fix this issue (one of your values has a `"` in it)

Answer (score -2):

Though this is not the best way to make updates to your tables. Prefer using prepare statements.
If your Insert works file,
try replacing your update with:

```
$update_pin =$db->update("UPDATE `card_pins` SET `status_pin`=1 WHERE `pin_number`=".$pin_num");
```

Comment: You have made it even worse: `$pin_num` will be injected the exact same way as in the OP's code - with the sql injection problem - and you have broken it further by adding spaces behind the table- and column names.

Comment: Thank @Netham it has works for me. i realize that it was my update query that is causing the error and i used the one you suggest and it works fine. Thanks once again

Comment: @jeroen Thanks for pointing the spaces, I missed it. Updated. Regarding the SQL injection problem, I mentioned beforehand to prefer using prepared statements. Seeing the mistake I feel the OP is a beginner so I suggested accordingly. If he carries on his path, he will come across the better ways for sure. But to educate him about sql injection, I don't think this is the best time and you already told in the comment.  Here the issue is not even related to PHP. It was a SQL issue and a basic one. Let him master that first. This is my opinion.

Comment: @jeroen A good analogy is electron orbitals. The story starts with a circle and with time and years develops into a probability function. You don't tell that on day one.